# How to use actionlistener in Scala Swing

Tags: scala, swing

I would like to make click counter in **Scala Swing**. I used for this ActionListener interface. But I don't know if I did it correctly. The program works, but I want to find out how to do this according to best practies. I will be very thankful for the answer how to do it correctly.

```scala
import javax.swing._
import java.awt._
import java.awt.event._

class UI extends JFrame {

  var title_ : String = "Hello, Swing in Scala"
  setTitle(title_)

  val textArea = new JTextArea
  var text : String = "Hello, Swing world in Scala!"
  textArea.setText(text)
  val scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea)

  val panel = new JPanel
  var text2 : String = "Click Here"
  val button =new JButton(text2)
  panel.add(button)

  var clicks:Int = 0

  def onClick(): Unit = {
    clicks += 1
    text = "Number of button clicks: " + clicks.toString
    textArea.setText(text)
  }

  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener {
    override def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent): Unit = onClick() })

  getContentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER)
  getContentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH)
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
  setSize(new Dimension(600, 400))
  setLocationRelativeTo(null)

  def display() {
    setVisible(true)
  }
}

object SwingExample extends App {
    val ui = new UI
    ui.display()
    println("End of main function")
}
```

Comment: This kind of question is often better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. It looks like you're asking for help along the lines of what they list in their ["What topics can I ask about here?
" page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are simple things, which improve code quality and maintainability.

it seems that `text`, `text2` and `title_` can remove and put that value directly into.

to shorten it, try this statement for the `onClick`

```scala
def onClick(): Unit = {
    clicks += 1
    textArea.setText(s"Number of button clicks: $clicks")
  }
```

see [String Interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

you can shorten your ActionListener by

```scala
button.addActionListener(e => onClick())
```